# Mongodb c# 2.0 driver doesn't ignore extra elements

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm using the 2.0 mongodb c# driver. 
I have 2 classes:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class A{...}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class B:A{...}
```

This is my code:

```
public async Task<List<A>> getList(string X)
{
    var collection = db.GetCollection<A>("myCollection");
    var filter = Builders<A>.Filter.Eq("fieldA", X);
    List<A> ansList = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

    return ansList;
}
```

On my computer everything works just fine, but for some reason on other computers  the function returns a `List<B>` which contains the full objects saved in the DB. Obviously I don't want to expose all the fields to the users therefore I must return a List without class B's fields.